# Gnu Radio osmocom sink, how to disable the sink if its not needed?

Tags: gnuradio

Hy i am trying to build a fm repeater station with a bladerf,as a demo.
I am couriouse that you can't really disable the osomocom sink, not by a variable nor by an input.

The workaround i'm currently using is that i set the frequency of the sink to 0.

Is this the right Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the frequency is a little bit slow, when open/close latency matters. I would suggest to use a `Multiply const` block. Setting the multiplier variable to 0, would result to a signal with zero amplitude, thus is like you disabled the transmission. However, the DAC of bladerf, would still process the zero samples, so the carrier at the center frequency will be there too.

If you want to entirely close the transmission of the bladerf, you can send an appropriate tag as part of the signal stream to the bladerf indicating the start or end of transmission. However, I do not now if `osomocom` sink block supports it.